# How to get the device id of a windows phone 8 using phonegap which will not change for every installation?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I have written a code to get the device id from the windows phone 8, i am sending request to the server from the application where i set the device id as the UniqueId, but for every time when i uninstall and install the application again new UUID is generated in the server how to make it unique which will not change for every installation.

here is my code to get UUID using phonegap. :-

```
var variable=device.uuid;
```

Need Help ! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know after a long search there is no kind of device id in windows phone. What I ever use is

```
string deviceID = Windows.Phone.System.Analytics.HostInformation.PublisherHostId;
```

You need to grant acces to ID_CAP_IDENTIY_DEVICE capability in order to use it. This is a specific id for each device and specific app, so same app in same device would generate ever same PublisherHostId.

Answer (score 0):

When buit my multi-user application, it took me a lot to figure out how to generate a unique id which contained just letters and digits (no special chars) and finally I found this as best solution:

```
Dim DeviceID = BitConverter.ToString(DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId")).Replace("-", String.Empty)
```

The ID doesn't change even if the phone is reset and MS account is changed.